# Problema em Context e SharedPreferences no android com serviço

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando criar um serviço no android, ele está pronto porém na execução a aplicação para. Se eu comentar as variaveis ctx e prefs, funciona porém preciso delas, podem me dizer se há algo de errado que não ví ? Já estou há bastante tempo e sinceramente não encontro o problema. Segue abaixo o código

Obs: Já está tudo certo no manifest.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import br.newm.alvomobile.database.EtapaPersistencia;
import br.newm.alvomobile.database.OSPersistencia;
import br.newm.alvomobile.webservice.OSWebService;
import br.newm.biblioteca.utils.AndroidUtils;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
public class DownloadManager extends Service implements Runnable{
   private Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
   private SharedPreferences prefs;
   private int id_usuario;
   private OSWebService oswebservice;
   private OSPersistencia ospersistencia;
   private String TAG = "DOWNLOAD-SERVICE";
}
```

Comment: Tente pegar o context em algum método do Service, como por exemplo o onBind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove apenas a varivável `ctx` e utiliza o `getApplicationContext()` da classe Service onde for necessário. 
Ex.:

```
public void test(){
     TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Comment: e quanto ao SharedPreferences ?

Comment: Compilando o código com o atributo (variável) prefs que não vai dar erro.

Comment: Obrigado cara, funcionou.